# Primefaces generate two columns in data rows instead of one

Tags: primefaces

I get a trouble with Primefaces 6.1, it's a migration from primefaces 3.4, and it works correctly in 3.4.

I don't know why but for each column, the datable create 2 column inside the data only.

One is empty and the other with the data filled inside.

And because of this, my table is completly transformed from the initial state

[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E68s.png)

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWgnx.png)

Is someone know why it's happening ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: put more code please